# php set_include_path drives me crazy

Tags: php, include-path, set-include-path

I need to include a file in php so I do

```
$web_proc = '../res/proc'; //variable read from config file I can't change
//in my file
include_once($web_proc . '/check_sprache.php');
```

and PHP outputs:

> Warning: include_once(../res/proc/check_sprache.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf/rechnung.php on line 62
>   Warning:
>   include_once(): Failed opening '../res/proc/check_sprache.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.:') in
>   /Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf/rechnung.php on line 62

So I change the include path:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

and try it again, but PHP outputs:

> Warning: include_once(../res/proc/check_sprache.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf/rechnung.php on line 62
>   Warning:
>   include_once(): Failed opening '../res/proc/check_sprache.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.::/Users/user/Sites/site/res/') in
>   /Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf/rechnung.php on line 62

But if if I do

```
include_once(dirname(__DIR__). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $pfadweb_proc . '/check_sprache.php');
```

it works. But this is no solution, since the included file includes more files with a relative path, so they are alse not found.

So either I misunderstand the PHP include path, or it's just trolling me.

Can anybody help?

Comment: PHPs `include_path` is only used for unanchored paths (no leading `/` or `.` or `..` relations). If you're unable to use relative paths, use `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`-bound ones.

Comment: @mario no no no! Why introduce an external dependency like document root? It excludes you from running scripts under any environment other than a web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The include path looks odd in the second example; You have two `PATH_SEPARATOR` characters and a trailing `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` though I doubt this is the problem.

Try this one out instead

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, [ // use array() if PHP < 5.4
    dirname(__DIR__), // this should be /Users/user/Sites/site/res
    get_include_path()
]));

include_once 'proc/check_sprache.php';
```

This will add the parent directory (`/Users/user/Sites/site/res`) of the CWD (`/Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf`) to your include path.

Any `include` statements in any other files can use a relative path from `/Users/user/Sites/site/res`.

Comment: Have tried this, but there is no change. still the same warning, unless the path is now the other way round: Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../res/proc/check_sprache.php' for inclusion (include_path='/Users/user/Sites/site/res:.:') in /Users/user/Sites/site/res/pdf/rechnung.php on line 67

Comment: @bj99 Why are you still including `../res` when calling `include`? My answer specifically shows you what to use

Comment: look at the changes I made to my initial post. I cant change the var $web_proc. :-/ And also the files included by check_sprache.php are included by using the same variable $web_proc in the include statement.

Comment: @bj99 Yeah, would have been nice to know that initially. Relative paths **with** directory traversal in a config file sounds like a ridiculous idea. Also, what's the point in having a config file you can't change?

Comment: the config file is given from site admin, and changing would break the include behaviour of the rest of the the page :-( So it's not possible to use relative paths with set_include_path?

Comment: @bj99 So where does the *"site admin"* expect that path to be relative from? It's just stupid. Anyway, why can't you ignore the config file and write code that works?

Comment: two folders above the folder i'm working in. But have now contacted the admin, since i think instead of defining `$web_proc = '../res/proc';` it will be the same to do: `$paths = array(dirname(__DIR__), get_include_path()); set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths));` in the config file and leave away the dots (`$web_proc = 'res/proc';`)!